# Android tcp socket connection slow

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, delay, lag

I have set up a server on my computer in java, and the client is my android phone.

I am trying to simulate the mouse behavior in my app but the problem is even though at the first minutes everything runs smoothly, in the end there is a huge delay between client and server.

**Server code**

```
    try {
        System.out.println(InetAddress.getLocalHost());

        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444); // Server socket
        serverSocket.setReceiveBufferSize(10000);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not listen on port: 4444");
    }

    System.out.println("Server started. Listening to the port 4444");


        try {

            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); // accept the client connection
            System.out.println("connection initiated");
            DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

            DataOutputStream dout= new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

            /* do my things here */
            din.close();
            dout.close();
            clientSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Problem in message reading "+ex);
            }
```

**Client code**

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        Socket socket = null;

        try {
            //Inet4Address.getLocalHost().toString(); //InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress().toString();
            System.out.println(dstAddress);
            socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);
            socket.setSendBufferSize(10000);
            DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            dout = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            dout.writeUTF(kappa);


            response = "sent to server";

            String msg = din.readUTF();
            response += msg;
            din.close();
            dout.close();
            socket.close();



        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = e.toString();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

(kappa is a global string that i modify each time.)

What might be the case?

Comment: `/* do my things here */`. Show at least how you read and write.

Comment: Why are you creating a new socket/client for every string? Why not keep the connection open?

Comment: `(kappa is a global string that i modify each time.)`. How many characters do you send every time? And how often?

Comment: oops sorry, thats how i read the message
`String msg = din.readUTF();
    System.out.println("Pressing " + msg); `

I have several buttons on my android, when i click button x , kappa ="x" .
I send data as soon as the user clicks a button

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved, i changed to udp connection and now there is no delay